How to run api's as aync waterfall and pass response and header cookie to other api's Node.js
I have
login api,
create post api,
upload post api,
schedule post api
I have to do login first and get the cookie from that api and set that cookies to rest of the api's.
Once cookies is set need to create post api in the response we will get post id that post id we need to append it to the upload post and schedule post url to schedule the post in FB.
So now I have all the api's written separately and manually passing cookie and postId to the api's.
So how can we achieve this in single api, so that Front end can use one single api to create post on Facebook.
api's are as below.
Controller.ts
@Post()
  async socialPostLogin() {
    return this.woovlyService.socialPostLogin();
  }

  @Post('createpost')
  async createPost() {
    return this.woovlyService.createPost();
  }

  @Put('uploadpost')
  async uploadPost() {
    return this.woovlyService.uploadPost();
  }

  @Post('schedulePost')
  async schedulePost() {
    return this.woovlyService.schedulePost();
  }

service.ts
async socialPostLogin() {
    const options = {
      url: LOGINURL,
      headers: LOGINHEADERS,
      auth: CREDENTIALS,
    };
    let socialPostLoginResponse;
      socialPostLoginResponse = await this.httpService.axiosRef.post(`${options.url}`, options.auth, {
        headers: options.headers,
      });
    return socialPostLoginResponse?.data;
  }

  async createPost() {
    const options = {
      url: POSTURL,
      headers: POSTHEADERS,
      body: POSTBODY,
    };
    let createPostResponse;
      createPostResponse = await this.httpService.axiosRef.post(`${options.url}`, options.body, {
        headers: options.headers,
      });
    return createPostResponse?.data;
  }

  async uploadPost() {
    const options = {
      url: UPLOADPOSTURL,
      headers: UPLOADPOSTHEADERS,
      body: UPLOADPOSTBODY,
    };
    let uploadPostResponse;
      uploadPostResponse = await this.httpService.axiosRef.put(`${options.url}`, options.body, {
        headers: options.headers,
      });
    return uploadPostResponse;
  }

  async schedulePost() {
    const options = {
      url: SCHEDULEPOSTURL,
      headers: SCHEDULEPOSTHEADERS,
      body: SCHEDULEPOSTBODY,
    };
    let schedulePostResponse;
      schedulePostResponse = await this.httpService.axiosRef.post(`${options.url}`, options.body, {
        headers: options.headers,
      });
    return schedulePostResponse?.data;
  }

